# Optimise React loading

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

I'm using React hook render two apis. I have 40 choices in total, to finish all loading, it will take me half mins for about 40 choices loading, which is too long. How should I do to reduce the loading time on the Frontend React side?

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadingChoice(questionId)
    loadingCheckChoice(questionId, detail.participantId)
}, [questionId])

const loadingChoice = async (questionId) => {
    const query = {
        questionId,
    }
    try {
        const choicesData = await getChoices(query)
        const choicesNew = choicesData
        setChoices(choicesNew)
        const choicesNotApplicableChoicesNew = choicesNew.filter((choice) => choice.type === "Not Applicable")
        const choicesStandardChoices = choicesNew.filter((choice) => choice.type !== "Not Applicable")
        setChoicesNotApplicableChoices(choicesNotApplicableChoicesNew)
        setChoicesStandardChoices(choicesStandardChoices)
    } catch (e) {}
}

const loadingCheckChoice = async (questionId, participantId) => {
    const query = { questionId, participantId }
    try {
        const responsesData = await getResponses(query)
        if (responsesData.length) {
            const checkedChoice = responsesData[0].choice_id
            setCheckedRadio(checkedChoice)
        }
        handleProcessing()
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: I guess first option should be to make backend API's more faster. But still if you want to achieve more at frontend, then I guess you can have a look at useCallback() and useMemo() hooks to handle performance. Basically, these hooks will help you to prevent reloading/invoking API's when it's not necessary

Comment: Perhaps concurrent requests based on the scenario you have provided https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all